# MongoDb - Rejoining a split mapreduce task

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map reduce function that, for efficiency' sake, should not be run at once.  So I split it based on a range of ids, and as a result, I get a bunch of separate collections.  I now want to join them and combine all of the mapreduce results.  The resulting table should still only have one key, and an values array with the combined temp-table values.

I have tried using "reduce" in my output like so, so that the existing table just gets updated, but this doesn't work:

```
res = db.People.mapReduce(m, r, {query:{xyz}, out:{reduce:"FoodPerPeople"}});
```

(**edit**) It gives me nested arrays:

```
{
  "_id" : "Banana",
  "value" : ["Bart", ["Joe"]]
}
```

I understand why this is happening-- the re-reduce function is treating the inputted array of values as a value in and of itself.

Example of what I'm looking for:

COLLECTION 1:

```
{
  "_id" : "Banana",
  "value" : ["Bart"]
}
```

COLLECTION 2:

```
{
  "_id" : "Banana",
  "value" : ["Joe"]
}
```

COMBINED COLLECTION: - How do I get this?

```
{
  "_id" : "Banana",
  "value" : ["Bart", "Joe"]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify "this doesn't work"? Do you get an error, or just unexpected results?

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show your map and reduce functions?

Comment: I think that you need to show your original Map/Reduce functions. What you are describing *should* work with the `reduce` option, but your output suggests that your `map` and `reduce` functions may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have reduce function that cannot rereduce already reduced data. You should read this [technical explanation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Amoretechnicalexplanation) and try to make your reduce function match this criteria.